# Xamarin not showing images in some cases

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, button

I'm having some trouble getting Xamarin to show images in my mobile app. When I use Image to put an image in, it works fine, but when I try to set the same image as the titleIcon or put the image on a button, it doesn't work. Is there some fundamental difference for these cases?

Relevant setup:

```
public partial class ThisPage : ContentPage
{

  ...

  public ThisPage(string data)
  {
    Content = new ScrollView()
    {
      Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
      Margin = new Thickness(10, 0)
    };

    ...

    (Content as ScrollView).Content = new StackLayout()
    {
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    };

    ...

    StackLayout layout = (Content as ScrollView).Content as StackLayout;
```

Works perfectly fine

```
    Title = titleString;
```

Does not work!

```
    NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this as ContentPage, filename);
```

Works properly, showing that my titleIcon works perfectly fine as an image

```
    Image im = new Image
    {
      Source = filename,
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    };
    layout.Children.Add(im);
```

And as for the buttons...

```
    AddButton(buttonData, layout);

  ...

  }
  public void AddButton(string buttonData, StackLayout layout)
  {

    ...

    Button b = new Button
    {
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
      //CornerRadius = 14  //Does not compile
      BorderRadius = 14  //Gives a warning telling me that I should use CornerRadius instead
    };
```

This works fine

```
    b.Text = buttonText;
```

This doesn't work at all.

```
    b.Image = filename;
```

The button always appears on the page, it just never has an image on it. Making the button larger manually and/or omitting text doesn't cause the image to appear either.

```
    layout.Children.Add(b);
  }
}
```

More data:

Testing using Xamarin Live app on my DuraForce Pro running Android version 6.0.1.

The "run" button in Visual Studio Community 2015 says "KYOCERA KYOCERA-E6820 Player (Android 6.0 - API23)".

The version of Xamarin.Forms installed into the project (NuGet) is Latest stable 2.5.0.280555

EDIT:

Thanks to Dennis Schröer below, images now work fine for buttons, but they're still not working as a title icon.

The image I'm trying to use for a title icon is a jpg that's 80 x 578 pixels.

It's in the Android sub-project's Resources/drawable folder as an AndroidResource and the iOS sub-project's Resources folder as a BundleResource.

I cannot test the iOS version of the app yet, as I very recently became unable to update to the latest version of XCode. (The latest version is incompatible with the Mac I was previously connecting my PC to for compiling the iOS version). Because of this, I'm only debugging the Android version for now.

I've also tried setting the property directly in the page's xaml file, to no avail:

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApplicationName.Views/ThisPage"
             NavigationPage.TitleIcon="Logo.jpg"
</ContentPage>
```

I've also tried to add it directly into Toolbar.axml as an ImageView, but that was not successful either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/Logo.jpg"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
  />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

For anyone who wants to see what change I made based on Dennis Schröer's suggestion, here's the new AddButton:

```
public void AddButton(String current, StackLayout layout)
{
    string[] segments = current.Split('|');
    string link = null;
    Button b = null;
    Image im = null;

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string segment in segments)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    link = segment;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                {
                    if (segment.Length > 0)
                    {
                        b = new Button
                        {
                            Text = segment,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                            //CornerRadius = 14  //Does not compile: "'Button' does not contain a definition for 'CornerRadius'
                            BorderRadius = 14  //Gives a warning: "'Button.BorderRadius' is obsolete: 'BorderRadius is obsolete as of 2.5.0. Please use CornerRadius instead.'"
                        };
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    im = new Image
                    {
                        Source = segment,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                    };
                }
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (im != null)
    {
        TapGestureRecognizer tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        if ((link.StartsWith(c_linkType)) || (link.StartsWith(c_mailType)))
        {
            tap.Tapped += (o, e) =>
            {
                LinkClicked(link);
            };
        }
        else
        {
            tap.Tapped += (o, e) =>
            {
                ButtonClicked(link);
            };
        }
        im.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
        layout.Children.Add(im);
    }

    if (b != null)
    {
        if ((link.StartsWith(c_linkType)) || (link.StartsWith(c_mailType)))
        {
            b.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            b.TextColor = Color.Blue;
            b.BorderColor = Color.White;
            b.BorderWidth = 0;
            b.Clicked += (o, e) =>
            {
                LinkClicked(link);
            };
        }
        else
        {
            b.BackgroundColor = new Color(186.0 / 256.0, 39.0 / 256.0, 45.0 / 256.0);
            b.TextColor = Color.White;
            b.Clicked += (o, e) =>
            {
                ButtonClicked(link);
            };
        }
        layout.Children.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52337/navigationpage-settitleicon).

Comment: I found that when initially researching how to get images to display at all. That page has the information that helped me get Image working and let me know about SetTitleIcon(). As best I can tell though, based on the page you linked, my code for the title icon should be working.

Comment: So, the image still not display?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: In case you don't find a solution: You could use an `Image` with a `TapGestureRecognizer` as an alternative to a `Button`.

Comment: Thank you. That was successful for creating image buttons. Now I just need title icons to work...

Comment: Not yet, no. It creates several compiler errors that I'm still looking into. I've added 'using Android.Widget;' to fix one of them, but there are still two more: "'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'toolbarImage'" and "'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'Logo'". I've already tried doing a clean build. I'm looking into what else might cause these sorts of errors.

Comment: Can you show where is your `Logo`? Please show me a picture. Or please try `logo` not `Logo`.

Comment: Resource.designer.cs wasn't updating. I cleared it and can now see toolbarImage in Id and Logo in Drawable within that file. Now it's giving me a different compilation error that I'm looking into: "Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='."

Comment: @GeekyGuy83 So, this problem have been solved? Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Possibly, but I haven't been able to compile it yet to see. Once I know for certain, I will either mark your answer as accepted or respond here to comment further.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. I was able to fix the assembly issue, but MainActivity.cs is refusing to see that what I'm referencing is within Resource.Id & Resource.Drawable. If I set my compile target to an Android version beyond what I'm able to test, I can compile, but I cannot test in that case, so it doesn't help me. Also, the resulting app needs to be accessible to general users, so an OS version that AT&T has not yet pushed out as an update is not a realistically viable target platform.

Answer (score 1):

> I've also tried to add it directly into Toolbar.axml as an ImageView, but that was not successful either:

Don't add `.jpg`, please use this:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/Logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
  />
```

Or you can add `android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"` to your `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
      />
```

And in your `MainActivity` add this below `LoadApplication(new App());`:

```
        ImageView toolbarImg = this.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.toolbarImage);
        toolbarImg.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Logo);
```